# Returning full path image in JSON with strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, strapi

Hello does anyone know how to return the full file path i.e image in strapi something like http://localhost:1337/uploads/test_2_63154b8b0d.png instead of the relative path (/uploads/test_2_63154b8b0d.png)

i was trying make a controller like below

```
/**
 * achievement controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::achievement.achievement', {
    async find(ctx) {
      let achievements = await strapi.query('achievements').find(ctx.query);
  
      achievements = achievements.map((achievement) => {
        if (achievement.images) {
          // Append the full URL to each image in the 'images' array
          achievement.images = achievement.images.map((image) => ({
            ...image,
            url: strapi.config.server.url + image.url,
          }));
        }
        return achievement;
      });
  
      return achievements;
    },
});
```

but i got 500 error

Here my data

```
image   
data    
id  1
attributes  
name    "test 2.png"
alternativeText null
caption null
width   970
height  544
formats {…}
hash    "test_2_63154b8b0d"
ext ".png"
mime    "image/png"
size    26.22
url "/uploads/test_2_63154b8b0d.png"
previewUrl  null
provider    "local"
provider_metadata   null
createdAt   "2023-10-03T06:43:32.669Z"
updatedAt   "2023-10-03T06:43:32.669Z"
```

The expected output data

```
image   
data    
id  1
attributes  
name    "test 2.png"
alternativeText null
caption null
width   970
height  544
formats {…}
hash    "test_2_63154b8b0d"
ext ".png"
mime    "image/png"
size    26.22
url "http://localhost:1337/uploads/test_2_63154b8b0d.png"
previewUrl  null
provider    "local"
provider_metadata   null
createdAt   "2023-10-03T06:43:32.669Z"
updatedAt   "2023-10-03T06:43:32.669Z"
```

Comment: Just quick question, why do you need to return it with the root url. This is something that you can append in your frontend application?  Or to simplify, just use an image provider like cloudinary or s3 bucket that will return the full url.  That is typically what I do wiht my projects in deployment.